# Resolve MainPage from IServiceProvider in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I created a new dotnet maui project and want to resolve `MainPage` from `IServiceProvider`.

I added to `MauiProgram.cs` the line `builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();`. Instead of (`App.xaml.cs`):

```cs
    public partial class App : Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new MainPage();
        }
    }
```

I want to retrieve or somehow access `MauiApp` to resolve `MainPage` from `IServiceProvider`. Something like that:

```cs
    public partial class App : Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var mauiApp = (MauiApp)this;
            MainPage = mauiApp.Services.GetService(typeof(MainPage)) as ContentPage;
        }
    }
```

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MauiProgram.cs:

Add Singletons for any services you need:

```
   public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
       builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
       builder.Services.AddSingleton<IGoodbyeWorldService, GoodbyeWorldService>();
    }
```

in App.Xaml.cs:

Include the MainPage in the arguements of the App method and assign to MainPage:

```
    public App(MainPage page) 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = page;
    }
```

Then in MainPage.xaml.cs include the service you need in the arguments:

```
    public MainPage(IGoodbyeWorldService service)
    {
     InitializeComponent();
     lblOne.Text = service.SayGoodbye();
    }
```

Comment: What I was looking for was `public App(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)`. Thanks!

Comment: @Briefkasten Hi, come to the same Q, any final code gist to share?